# Pass select value to masterpage when it changes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, select, href, master-pages

I am working with an ASP.NET application for my company. I have a MasterPage with a navbar with options. One of the options displays another page but now the company ask me to pass a parameter to the link. I already find out how to do that (with a property in the Main.Master class). But here is where I have the problem. Tha parameter must be the value from a select element in the main page and it must be saved in the property as soon as the user select one.

I can't call the onChange event because the element isn't an asp component and i mustn't change it because and API (Select2) need it to be a normal html element. But maybe there is a way; if you know please tell me how.

I also try to retrieve the value with JS and pass it from to the master page with ajax, but it didn't work because it only calls a static method and a static method can't use the MasterType reference to change the Main.Master.

So, does exist some way to achieve what I want? Also, sorry for not post code but this is a bit confidential.

Answer (score 0):

yes,  you can. Probably the most easy?

Well, in your main menu (likey based on the bootstrap default menu), you can in place of a href link, drop in a menu button (use a link button).

So, say we have this menu markup

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="My Test Update" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So, you have your standard menus - hrefs - they jump without any code.

But, note the last one menu - the My Test Update.

That is a link button. so now you have a event stub in your master page code stub.

You get a menu like this:

[image]

And I just dropped in a text box on that page. Like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
    <p>Your app description page.</p>
    <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>


    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

</asp:Content>
```

so far, that's as plan jane as it can be.

So, now how can we pick up the text box? Well, you can do this, in master page - code behind:

```
 Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim MyContent As ContentPlaceHolder
    MyContent = Me.FindControl("MainContent")

    Dim MyTextBox As TextBox = MyContent.FindControl("TextBox1")

    Debug.Print("text box value = " & MyTextBox.Text)
    Response.Redirect("~/RadioFun.aspx")

End Sub
```

So notice how we simply grabbed the text box value. Now how to pass to the next page? Gee, you could use session, or use that value as a parameter in the url that you jump to, or whatever.

So, by replacing the menu navigation from a href to a link button? Well, it looks the same, but now you get a event code behind in your master page code. And as above shows, it quite easy to pull/pluck out the values - at that point, as noted, you can shove that value into session() and then jump to the page that the menu click button (link button) supposed to navigate too. You also cound consider using post-back URL. if you look close, note that Page.PreviousPage is a property of the page. The "previous" page ONLY works on first page load, and ONLY works if the button in question uses a postback URL. So, we could dump the linkbutton event (but still use the link button). Set the post-back url of the link button in the markup. That way, then on page load (only first load - postback = false, then you are free to use page.prevous - and you can use find control against that page like I did as per above - your free to grab "many" controls - not just pass one value.

PostBackURL is thus another way - and I often use PostBackURL in a button dropped on a page - it will navigate to the new page - does so without a event code behind stub, but MORE important using PostBackURL settings for that button/control ALSO enables you to use/get/grab the page.previousPage property - that previous page is in fact the WHOLE previous page that was passed to the server - and you can then grab say values from a WHOLE form or whatever. Just keep in mind that since you have a master page, then the two step process (get the content page, then then a find control on that page is still required).

So either above approaches will work.